# How do I migrate mysql .frm and .ibd files to sqlite?

Tags: mysql, migration, sqlite

Mysql seems to not work anymore on my machine. I have spend way too much time trying to fix it but without success.
But I found out that sqlite does all the stuff I need so why not just change to it. But since mysql does nothing I also can not use mysqldump or anything, and all the tutorials I find on the internet are using either this or something else that needs mysql running. 
But I have access to the database files, specifically the .frm and .ibd files. How can I transfer them to a fresh sqlite install? If it matters I am onManjaro Linux.

Comment: Is this actually MySQL, or is it MariaDB? (I understand MariaDB is favoured by Arch Linux.) I suggest you ask a new question about how to fix your MySQL/MariaDB installation, and then you can decide if you want to migrate to SQLite or not.

Comment: @dbdemon I have already tried numerous things that should fix the problem, I have also tried it on Debian (also with MariaDB) but I just can't get it to work. It was no big database and I could totally just recreate it by hand but I can't read the entries in the files. It seems to be some kind of encoding problem since most characters are just @s in vim. But no matter which encoding I choose it is mostly just glibberish.

Comment: Luca, the data files are binary and are not intended to be readable/writable in vim or any other editor like that. You really need a MariaDB server (mysqld) and a suitable client in order to do that.

Comment: @dbdemon well, that sucks. But thanks alot for helping a newbie out. I will now see if my data is worth the effort as it is just a hobby project or if I will try to get MariaDB running again.

Comment: Glad I could help, and like I said feel free to ask a new question if you decide to try and fix the MariaDB installation. There are lots of knowledgable people on here, all happy to help with that.

Comment: ok, it's a bit late, but: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html. I do not know if such a page does exist for MariaDB...